# How to use Apache Solr with Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, solr

I am new to Apache Solr and Laravel. I want to make a website that use Apache Solr as its search platform, and Laravel for my PHP framework. I already followed a few guides that I found while googling:

1. https://petericebear.github.io/laravel-php-solarium-integration-20160725/
2. https://teguharief.wordpress.com/2018/05/01/creation-search-engine-on-laravel-sites-using-solr/

I have followed each steps and got stuck at SolariumServiceProvider.php

Here is the code for SolariumServiceProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Solarium\Client;

class SolariumServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $defer = true;

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return  void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(Client::class, function ($app) {
            return new Client($app->['config']['solr']); <- What is the correct syntax?
        });
    }

    public function provides()
    {
        return [Client::class];
    }
}
```

The solr.php is already in config as shown on the image:

[config/solr.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsYxy.jpg)

and then I got this error.

**Solarium\Core\Client\Client::__construct(): Argument #1 ($adapter) must be of type Solarium\Core\Client\Adapter\AdapterInterface, array given, called in ...**

Anyone who experienced with integrating laravel and Apache Solr can help me solve this problem?

Comment: read the documentation. since you are using solarium 6 then instantiate it with the right parameters https://github.com/solariumphp/solarium for the event dispatcher, use the illuminate one

Comment: Can you show me on how to instantiate it with the right parameter? I am so lose even after reading the documentation

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(Client::class, function ($app) {
            $adapter = new Solarium\Core\Client\Adapter\Curl();
            $eventDispatcher = new Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher();
            return new Client($adapter, $eventDispatcher, $app->['config']['solr']);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

create a config file with SOLR_HOST,SOLR_PORT,SOLR_PATH,SOLR_CORE
create a new provider and register this code

```
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Solarium\Client;
use Solarium\Core\Client\Adapter\Curl;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher;

class SolariumServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $defer = true;

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return  void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $adapter = new Curl();
        $eventDispatcher = new EventDispatcher();
        $this->app->bind(Client::class, function ($app) use ($adapter, $eventDispatcher) {
            return new Client($adapter, $eventDispatcher, $app['config']['solarium']);
        });
    }

    public function provides()
    {
        return [Client::class];
    }
}
```

in config/app.php
`App\Providers\SolariumServiceProvider::class,`

and in last create a controller and put this code to check if solr works or not

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class SolariumController extends Controller
{
    protected $client;

    public function __construct(\Solarium\Client $client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    public function ping()
    {
        // create a ping query
        $ping = $this->client->createPing();

        // execute the ping query
        try {
            $this->client->ping($ping);
            return response()->json('OK');
        } catch (\Solarium\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json('ERROR', 500);
        }
    }
}
```

if you still get confused [follow this link](https://gist.github.com/MonrealRyan/279d87ed532394c0f9abd559065cf868)